# React Native: How to move to the next input filed after pressing the “next” keyboard button?

Tags: javascript, android, ios, reactjs, react-native

```
          <TextInput
            // ...
            returnKeyType = {"next"}
            returnKeyType='go'
          />
```

this code[image] is not leading the 'go'/'next' to next input field
How to Add "next" and "previous" arrows to the keyboard in iOS. And Set the "return"/"next" button on the keyboard to take the user to the next field in react native.

Comment: You have to implement the method called `onSubmitEditing` which is triggered when pressed that button

Comment: use enter event and by using input property focus you can move the cursor to next input

for ref you can check here https://davidltran.com/blog/focus-next-input-react-native/#:~:text=By%20default%2C%20the%20React%20Native,enter%22%20on%20your%20virtual%20keyboard.

Comment: @RohitKumar Thanks a lot this helped!!!    ```onSubmitEditing={() => this.passwordRef.focus()}  ref={ref => this.passwordRef = ref}```

Answer (score 2):

You can focus next input using reference of text input.

```
      const refPasswordInput = useRef(null);

      const focusOnPassword = () => {
        if (refPasswordInput && refPasswordInput.current) {
           refPasswordInput.current.focus();
        }
      };

      const hideKeyboard = () => {
        Keyboard.dismiss()
      };

      <TextInput
        ...
        blurOnSubmit={false}
        returnKeyType="next"
        onSubmitEditing={focusOnPassword}
      />

      <TextInput
        ref={refPasswordInput}
        ...
        returnKeyType="done"
        onSubmitEditing={hideKeyboard}
      />
```